# Change text color base on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text "I have read and agree...." to a different color when the checkbox is being clicked. Does it require a DIV & label to be place for both the text & checkbox ?.

I also notice the checkbox would be move to next line, when I place in the div class="checkbox" & label

```
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

JS

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);

    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#termsChkbx').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent('p').css('color','black');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent('p').css('color','red')
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#termsChkbx').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent().css('color','black');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent().css('color','red')
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
```